# BMW 530xd e60 2008 diesel engine turns but won't start

Tags: engine, starting, bmw, diesel

I have a problem with my BMW, just bought it, previous owner hasn't been facing such problems. When the engine is cold for e.g.: after night. Outside temperature is about -4 to +1 degree, engine won't start, it just turns over and over, but is not firing up. Battery is good, even tried to connect the wires from the other car to that one to under the hood being + and -. In the BMW center they've done all the diagnostics, checked everything related to this problem. All seems to be OK, but obviously not.

Computer is showing "Fuel pump fault", but in the BMW center they told me that fuel pump is good and working as it should be. As well is glow plugs. When the engine is warm, it starts without any problems. It just happens when it's cold.

I am really out of options here, please advice.

***EDIT***

Also forgot to mention. When I start the ignition, all yellow lights goes off after a few seconds, but the one, engine light:

[image]

should be left lighting, but it doesn't appear at all at that point when I am not able to start a car, when the engine is just turning over and over. Once it appears engine starts without any problems and the light goes off.

Comment: Did you get a print out of the codes? Because of the running OK when warm it is pointing to fuel system, including glow plugs or its module. The fuel system can drain back over night with a faulty fuel pump, and the turning over and over can be a re-priming of the system.

Comment: Yeah I did. All codes were deleted yesterday in the BMW center. But today the same problem occurs.

Comment: The dtc codes are an important first step and should not be deleted until the car has been fixed. Do you know what they were?

Comment: They were: "Fuel pump fault", "Start assistance inactive", "4x4 disabled", "Fault in drive", but they are all gone the second engine is running. Something is wrong with electricity system, looks like it doesn't get the power at that point and automatically fuel pump is blocked, and the error occurs, but once engine is running there are no extraneous sounds or something like that..

Comment: You can buy an OBD2 wifi or bluetooth ELM327 diagnostic plug for your car on ebay for around ten British pounds. You can then download a program called Torque Pro off of the internet for a further couple of pounds. You will then be able to view your codes and edit your question with the codes. 'Fuel fault' and 'start assistence inactive' are fuel system faults. '4x4 disabled' and 'fault in drive' are transmission faults but will come up under OBD2. An OBD2 code will follow the form 'P0xxx or P1xxx'

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to find out those codes tomorrow, should be able to see them when I pair my phone with the car via bluetooth. I've downloaded Torque Pro android app. Doing more research on this it seems that fuel pump relay is the culprit of this problem, will let you know anyway what was wrong.

Comment: If the fuel pump is OK, it could be the fuel pump ECU http://www.realoem.com/bmw/showparts.do?model=NY71&mospid=50111&btnr=16_0555&hg=16&fg=15 or, even more likely, the fuel pump relay http://www.realoem.com/bmw/showparts.do?model=NY71&mospid=50111&btnr=12_1205&hg=12&fg=35

Comment: How old is your battery? Maybe it is too worn out and it is not able to provide enough 'Volts' to your car's system.

Comment: Was there any resolution to this? Or is the car still not starting?

Answer (score 1):

From what it sounds like the light is showing after the glow plugs are hot and Ready glow plugs take around 15-30 seconds to warm up and if you are turning it over and over without them hot 1. It will not start 2. You are going to throw codes. How long do you wait to start turning over the engine after you turn the key on? On a car in cold weather you should be waiting about 30 seconds. On Big trucks and tractors you are looking at more like 60 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

May be BMW center is wrong or i am wrong.
A no start condition is mostly a symptom of a failed fuel pump. A fuel pump with problems will often produce a loud whine. Worn brushes, commutators and broken/loose windings in the fuel pump motor or harness can also cause the vehicle to die. This often happens after driving a while. Such problems are very difficult to diagnose. Most late-model vehicles no longer have separately replaceable fuel filters.

OR your problem might be something else, this link might help you.

[LINK](http://autorepair.about.com/od/troubleshooting/a/ts_no-start.htm)